# Getting syntax error in bash case statement

Tags: linux, bash

I have written the following bash statement but getting an error while executing it

```
case "$var1" in
        *abc.com*)
                data+="found abc.com"
        ;;
        *)
case $Svar2 in
     1*) if [[  "$value" == 113* ]]  || [[ "$value" == 1122.168.52.* ]]
           then
               data+="value correctly set"
         fi
         ;;
        *)
     2*) if [[  "$value" == 114* ]]  || [[ "$value" == 115* ]]
              then
                  data+="value correctly set"
            fi
         ;;
        *)
        data+="value not set"
        ;;
esac
```

When I run the above command, I am getting an error `syntax error near unexpected token`)'`

Comment: You have two lines `*)` and `2*)` following each other without `;;`. You also don't have enough `esac`. The shell should give you a line number or show the problematic line as a hint where to look for the error.

Comment: would you mind helping with putting correct `esac`

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) would show you the problem immediately.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Which `case` is `*)` supposed to go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `*)` before the second case of `$Svar2`.

And you're missing the `esac` statement for `case $Svar2`.

```
case "$var1" in
    *abc.com*) data+="found abc.com" ;;
    *) case $Svar2 in
        1*) if [[  "$value" == 113* ]]  || [[ "$value" == 1122.168.52.* ]]
            then
                data+="value correctly set"
            fi ;;
        2*) if [[  "$value" == 114* ]]  || [[ "$value" == 115* ]]
            then
                data+="value correctly set"
            fi ;;
        *) data+="value not set" ;;
    esac ;;
esac
```